# Using GNUPlot inside Latex (TexStudio) for IEEE Tran

Tags: pdftex, ieeetran, gnuplot, ieee-style

I am trying to insert gnuplot inside my IEEE Tran paper (Platform is Windows). I am unable to do it correctly. Here is the code. The below give code is not working. No output is obtained. I am writing all the packages just in case they are required.

**Code 1**

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\ifCLASSINFOpdf

\else
\fi
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx,tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage[shell]{gnuplottex}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}


\begin{document}

\title{Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for Conferences}

\maketitle

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{Introduction}
I wish you the best of success.

\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=pdf,terminaloptions={font ",10" linewidth 3}]
plot sin(x), cos(x)
\end{gnuplot}
\end{document}
```

I also used the below given code but the margins are way too wide for a conference. Please suggest solutions for it. I would be happy to get some feedback on how to use epslatex inside the latex. Kindly, advice me for IEEE Tran.

**Code 2**

```
gnuplot> set terminal latex
Terminal type set to 'latex'
Options are '(document specific font) norotate'
gnuplot> set output 'plot.tex'
gnuplot> plot x**2
gnuplot> unset output
```

Below given I wrote in a latex file :

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\ifCLASSINFOpdf

\else
\fi
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx,tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage[shell]{gnuplottex}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}


\begin{document}

\title{Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for Conferences}

\maketitle

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{Introduction}
I wish you the best of success.
\input{plot.tex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can't you use a `figure*` environment?

Comment: \begin{figure*}
\input{plot.tex}
\end{figure*}  This is what I tried keeping everything else the same. Could you give me more input on how could I use figure* environment? I am a beginner here.

Comment: I just did what you were saying it worked but the problem is my document has two columns and when I use figure* it takes space in both the columns and pushes the text downwards. Is there a way I can keep this plot only on one column? Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I have found another bug here. The plot is completely black and white. I want it to be colored , I checked it somewhere else and I found that when we include plot.tex file inside figure* environment, the environment only gives black and white plots. How could I get colored plots?

Comment: The gnuplot terminal `pdf` requires the `color` option for colored output

Comment: @user56277: If you try to use `epslatex` you will get two files, a `.tex` and an `.eps` file, this won't work with `pdflatex` however. As such, the terminal option `pdf` to the gnuplot `environment` is contradictory.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I have posted something below, could you please give your comments on that one. I gave this command but it does not work - "set terminal latex color". I do not know the correct syntax for using pdf here.

Comment: @user56277: No, I wrote the *pdf terminal requires color* option.

Comment: Yes you are right. The idea is that I want to create a file "force.tex" and want to insert it into another tex file "main.tex" as shown below as a part of the solution. Kindly help me by answering that . I think I am very close but I do not know the correct keywords. Thanks!

Comment: I think, you are after `set terminal epslatex color` as described in the manual. Please have a look into http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.6/gnuplot.pdf

Comment: Thanks again! I tried it , it generates two files "force.tex" and "force.eps". I put these file names inside the "main.tex" file but nothing happens. Basically, it is not working. I tried several things but it is not working. Could it be because I am using Texstudio? It would be nice if you could try it and give me more idea about the solution. thanks!

Comment: @user56277 As indicated in the gnuplottex manual ( ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/gnuplottex/gnuplottex.pdf ) you have to use the epstopdf package, if you want to use the epslatex terminal with pdflatex. Probably easier would be a switch to the cairolatex terminal. You can have a look at the mentioned manual for examples of the different terminals. If it still doesn't work please post a _minimal_ working example, then I'd have another look at it.

Comment: Thanks John, I did use epstopdf package but it did not work. For the time being I have found a workaround . Now I am generating pdf files of my plots and then inserting them inside the "main.tex" file. I will try the other packages which are cairolatex or tikx and let you know. have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your code doesn't work are the `’` characters e.g. in `’$\cos(x)$’`.
Replace them with `'` and you get the desired output (so e.g. `’$\cos(x)$’` --> `'$\cos(x)$'` )

Besides that, the code works for me:

[image]

I'll update the manual in the next days, as the characters are shown wrong there, thank you!

Comment: I would like to welcome to TeX-SX in case we didn't already :)

Comment: Thanks John. I am glad you answered my question. It did not work for me. I tried several other things but it seems like TexStudio is not working for me. The example you gave me seems to be correct as well. I think my settings are not correct for Texstudio. I need to search more on how to setup GnuPlot compilation inside the Tex files for TexStudio.

Comment: @user56277 Could you attach your logfile? Maybe I can help then.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution for the question but this produces only black and white plots. This is a disappointment. Could somebody tell me how to produce colored plots ? I would be grateful to the person. Thanks!

This is the code for gnuplot

```
gnuplot> set terminal latex                                                                       
Terminal type set to 'latex'
Options are '(document specific font) norotate'
gnuplot> set output "force.tex"
gnuplot> set size 0.65,0.85    
gnuplot> plot  'force.dat' using 1:2 title 'Column' with lines, "force.dat" u 1:3 t 'Beam' w lines
points
```

This is the code that I gave in the pdf file in Tex Studio .

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\ifCLASSINFOpdf

\else
\fi

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx,tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}    
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}

\title{Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for Conferences}

\maketitle

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{Introduction}
I wish you the best of success.

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\input{force.tex}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This is the text file that I created

```
# This file is called   force.dat
# Force-Deflection data for a beam and a bar
# Deflection    Col-Force       Beam-Force 
0.000              0              0    
0.001            104             51
0.002            202            101
0.003            293            148
0.0031           294            148
0.004            282            204
0.0041           290            208
0.005            310            250
0.010            311            260
0.020            280            240
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend to use another terminal in gnuplot, as the latex terminal offers relatively bad output compared with other available terminals (e.g. cairolatex, epslatex and tikz).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution but I tried below given code. This might act as a solution to some people out there. This is an example that I tried from the manual -

> ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/gnuplottex/gnuplottex.pdf

Texstudio is not showing any errors but it is not plotting anything. I am not sure if I am making a mistake or not. I tried using cairolatex and epslatex. Here is the code. I have included all the packages that I included in my TexStudio. Texstudio just prints the caption in the pdf and nothing else.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\ifCLASSINFOpdf

\else
\fi

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx,tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
%\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}


\begin{document}

\title{Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for Conferences}

\maketitle

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{Introduction}
I wish you the best of success.
\begin{figure}%
\centering%
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=cairolatex, terminaloptions=color dashed]
set key box top left
set key width 4
set key height 0.25
set key spacing 1.2
set key opaque
set sample 1000
set xr [-5:5]
set yr [-1:1]
set xlabel ’$x$-label’
set ylabel ’$y$-label’
plot sin(x) w l lc 1 lw 3 t ’$\sin(x)$’,\
cos(x) w l lc 7 lw 3 t ’$\cos(x)$’,\
tan(x) w l lc 3 lw 3 t ’$\tan(x)$’,\
tanh(x) w l lc 4 lw 3 t ’$\tanh(x)$’
\end{gnuplot}
\caption{This is a simple example using the cairolatex-terminal.}%
\label{pic:cairolatex}%
\end{figure}%

\end{document}
```